# Images from custom theme are not in sources list on live website

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**SOLVED**

I had a typo on file name. M2 only includes images if they are being used.

---

On my computer all images from `mythemes/web/images` folder are under

```
/pub/static/frontend/Training/default/images (right side of screenshot),
```

But when I visit the site and check sources (left side of screenshot) there aren't any images from my theme there.

Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a typo on file name. M2 only includes images if they are being used.

Answer (score 2):

Please disable cache using command

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
```

delete all file and folders from pub/static and var (don't delete .htaccess) using command

```
rm -rf pub/static/ * 
rm -rd var/*
```

run command for deploay magento files

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and provide permission to pub/static and var as 755

```
 chmod -R 755 pub/static var
```

> Please note some commands might not work in Windows Operating System

Comment: I was already doing that before. It didn't help. Do I need to include those images in some .xml file or something?

Comment: Commands I ran `sudo rm -rf var/*` ,  `sudo rm -rf pub/static/*` , `sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` , `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/mg`

Answer (score 0):

@parasarora1303 is right but I'd like to add one more thing here and that is to remember to add your site locale whilst deploying the content.

By default, magento locale is set to en_US but if you have set the default local to let's say en_GB then the static content will only be deployed for en_US.

Run the following to deploy static content for your local.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

or

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy {Your_SET_LOCALE}
```

Comment: It is en_US and I already tried those commands before.

Comment: I have provided the general commands. If web has multi languages then they need to mention all languages with space like php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US